# flac terminal app no longer works - giving me libogg.0.dylib errors

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, flac

I've been a happy user of flac on the OS X Terminal. I mostly use it to either encode, or decode wav -> flac  or flac -> wav.

What I'm meeting nowadays is this:

```
flac -d *.flac
 dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/flac
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What should I do? I've tried to brew uninstall libogg and brew install libogg, but that did not actually help.

Is there some easy commandline version for OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 for unflac/flac or should I switch to some OS X app that does it for me? Which would you recommend?

Comment: I've always just used [Max](http://sbooth.org) …but I always prefer GUI to command line

Comment: Tetsujin: It seems that Max does not render fully WAV compatible .wav-files. Not a solution, unfortunately

Comment: compatible to what? I've used it quite happily for years

Comment: I found XLD to be the solution that did result in compatible wavefiles.
[XLD link for OSX](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html)

Comment: Yup - XLD is fine too, I use both - just Max is usually quicker to dial-in. XLD is only essential for 24-bit flac, as Max doesn't deal with those.

Comment: Seems that you tried to reinstall libogg when you should try to reinstall flac. `brew uninstall flac`, `brew install flac --with-libogg`.

Comment: @jherran hi, thanks. I did try your `brew uninstall flac` followed by `brew install flac --with-libogg`.

but the end result was this:
`flac -d shonuff.flac 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/flac
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
 /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

not entirely sure where to go from here.

Comment: Ok, try this one: `brew uninstall libogg`, and then `brew install libogg --universal`... may work.

Comment: @jherran that solved it! Thank you so so much!! Is there a way to tag your comment as the solution for this question? (sorry, I'm new here)

Comment: @esaruoho I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
brew uninstall libogg
```

and then:

```
brew install libogg --universal
```